# Accessing graph in ArcMap document using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, graph

I am trying to access an existing graph in an ArcMap document with arcpy.  I know how to create a new graph with arcpy, but I cannot seem to figure out how to access an existing graph in an ArcMap document with a standalone ar

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately arcpy does not have the ability to modify an existing graph through the API, just create new ones using MakeGraph_management.

Comment: I think @Guddie has answered this question so I recommend acceptance of his answer.